# How to delete duplicate objectID in ogrmerge?

Tags: geojson, merge, ogr2ogr, objectid

I am using ogrmerge to merge two GeoJSON files together. These two files can sometimes have duplicate **objectIDs**. Is there a way I can specify from the ogrmerge command options to only select distinct objectIDs or any other field for that matter?

I looked in the documentation but couldn't find any options to avoid duplicates.

Comment: Are the features with the same objectID full duplicates so that also all the other attributes are equal? If attributes differ, which feature would you like to drop? The first one, the latter one, or random?

Comment: yes they are full dupelicates. all the other attributes are equal.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are out of luck with ogrmerge which simply takes several inputs and appends then to one output. I am not sure if GDAL has a mechanism for making comparison between different data sources. Certainly you can filter the duplicates from the output but I believe that you would like to get rid of duplicates as early as possible.

There is a solution that uses OGR virtual format https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/vrt.html but I am not sure how effective it is with big datasets. The trick is that with a virtual vector system you can combine separate json inputs into one data source that allows to use SQL UNION function and UNION removes the duplicates.

Source data:

```
a.json
======
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID":2, "attr":"bb" }, "geometry": {"type":"Point","coordinates":[206,362]} },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID":3, "attr":"cc" }, "geometry": {"type":"Point","coordinates":[164,318]} }
]
}

b.json
======
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID":1, "attr":"aa" }, "geometry": {"type":"Point","coordinates":[170,352]} },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID":2, "attr":"bb" }, "geometry": {"type":"Point","coordinates":[206,362]} }
]
}
```

Write an ORG VRT file that combines these two datasets into one data source "union.vrt" with two layers:

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
        <OGRVRTLayer name="a">
            <SrcDataSource>a.json</SrcDataSource>
        </OGRVRTLayer>
        <OGRVRTLayer name="b">
            <SrcDataSource>b.json</SrcDataSource>
        </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

Test that there are two layers:

```
ogrinfo union.vrt
INFO: Open of `union.vrt'
      using driver `OGR_VRT' successful.
1: a (Point)
2: b (Point)
```

Now you can use normal SQL function UNION. See the result and notice that query returns 3 feautures, and duplicate feature "bb" appears only once.

```
ogrinfo -dialect SQLite -sql "select * from a UNION select * from b" union.vrt
INFO: Open of `union.vrt'
      using driver `OGR_VRT' successful.

Layer name: SELECT
Geometry: Point
Feature Count: 3
Extent: (164.000000, 318.000000) - (206.000000, 362.000000)
Layer SRS WKT:
...
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Geometry Column = GEOMETRY
ID: Integer (0.0)
attr: String (0.0)
OGRFeature(SELECT):0
  ID (Integer) = 1
  attr (String) = aa
  POINT (170 352)

OGRFeature(SELECT):1
  ID (Integer) = 2
  attr (String) = bb
  POINT (206 362)

OGRFeature(SELECT):2
  ID (Integer) = 3
  attr (String) = cc
  POINT (164 318)
```